# Annotated Controllers in Spring, passing parameter to jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to complete  [that tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) with annotated controllers. I got stuck on the Step 2. Here is what they have for Simple Controllers:

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String now = (new Date()).toString();
    logger.info("Returning hello view with " + now);

    return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp", "now", now);
}
```

I tried to replace it with

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showUserForm(ModelMap model)
{
    String now = (new Date()).toString();
    logger.info("Returning hello view with " + now);
    model.addAttribute("now", now);
    return "WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp";
}
```

But that parameter "now" is not read in hello.jsp (it could be accessed by the first link, I can't paste html here).

How can I transfer that parameter to hello.jsp?

Thanks!

Comment: It should work. Are you sure it doesn't?

Comment: Can you show us your JSP? You can format it just as your Java code.

Comment: it's really strange, it doesn't work in linux, but works in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be you're trying to use a scriptlet to output the data in your JSP. Like this:

```
<p><%= now %></p>
```

This will not work as the variable is not in the page scope but in the request scope. You should use EL to output the value, like this:

```
<p>${now}</p>
```

Or, if you want to use scriptlets, do something like this:

```
<p><%= pageContext.findAttribute("now") %></p>
```

If you could post your JSP code this would be quite helpful.

Comment: I guess that if it has worked before, he is using the proper construct.

Comment: Did it actually work with the first example? I'm not understanding this from the OP.

Comment: Scriptlet scope should not be confused with page scope.

Comment: After I tried using <%= pageContext.findAttribute("now") %> it started to work. But it's strange that <c:out value="${now}"/> works in Windows but not in Linux. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: for unknown reasons in linux I should add isELIgnored="false" to my page directove for jstl to work

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your views are resolved via a view resolver, and its default configuration includes the `WEB-INF/jsp` as prefix, and `.jsp` as suffix.

So the view name (the string the you should return) is just `"hello"`.

If this is not the case, please share your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and the jsp itself.

Answer (score -1):

Your `showUserForm()` method does not return a `ModelAndView` object. This is how the view gets data from your controller.

Comment: It's wrong, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments

Comment: Incorrect. The `ModelMap` is passed to the view before rendering.

Comment: Thank you. Learned something new. Still doesn't explain why it isn't working.